# How to run a docker instance with params in Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

In my macos, I want to run centos instance with like command:

```
docker run --rm -it --cap-add SYS_ADMIN os sh
```

but when I open the Docker Desktop there only can set Container Name and Volumes

[image]

how can I implement my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

To use Docker Desktop for running a container (though it is not recommended), you should select an image. Then, by clicking on the RUN command, it will prompt you to choose optional settings. You can configure the container with those settings.
[See this image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAeyz.png)